# LIMIT changing sort order on query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Two requests with differing LIMIT number are yielding different sorting results.

`SELECT "acgti"."id" AS "id", "acgti"."ac_node_id" AS "ac_node_id", "acgti"."ac_msn_number" AS "ac_msn_number", "acgti"."ac_production_site" AS "ac_production_site_short_name", "acgti"."ac_program_id" AS "ac_program_id", "acgti"."ac_fal_rank" AS "ac_fal_rank", "acgti"."ac_status" AS "ac_status", "acgti"."logical_station_production_site" AS "logical_station_production_site", "acgti"."logical_station_short_name" AS "logical_station_short_name", "acgti"."rgti_node_id" AS "rgti_node_id", "acgti"."rgti_release_number" AS "rgti_release", "acgti"."rgti_reference" AS "rgti_reference", "acgti"."rgti_title" AS "rgti_title", "acgti"."rgti_title_second_lang" AS "rgti_title_second_lang", "acgti"."status" AS "status", "acgti"."created_on" AS "created_on", "acgti"."updated_on" AS "updated_on", "acgti"."attestation_type" AS "attestation_type", "created_by"."fullname" AS "created_by", CONCAT("acgti"."ac_customer_version_name", '/', "acgti"."ac_customer_version_rank") AS "ac_version_and_rank" FROM "ac_gti" "acgti" LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "created_by" ON "created_by"."username"="acgti"."created_by"  LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "updated_by" ON "updated_by"."username"="acgti"."updated_by" WHERE "acgti"."ac_production_site" IN ('A350 TJN', 'A350 TLS') ORDER BY "acgti"."rgti_reference" ASC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 10`

Yields :

[image]

`SELECT "acgti"."id" AS "id", "acgti"."ac_node_id" AS "ac_node_id", "acgti"."ac_msn_number" AS "ac_msn_number", "acgti"."ac_production_site" AS "ac_production_site_short_name", "acgti"."ac_program_id" AS "ac_program_id", "acgti"."ac_fal_rank" AS "ac_fal_rank", "acgti"."ac_status" AS "ac_status", "acgti"."logical_station_production_site" AS "logical_station_production_site", "acgti"."logical_station_short_name" AS "logical_station_short_name", "acgti"."rgti_node_id" AS "rgti_node_id", "acgti"."rgti_release_number" AS "rgti_release", "acgti"."rgti_reference" AS "rgti_reference", "acgti"."rgti_title" AS "rgti_title", "acgti"."rgti_title_second_lang" AS "rgti_title_second_lang", "acgti"."status" AS "status", "acgti"."created_on" AS "created_on", "acgti"."updated_on" AS "updated_on", "acgti"."attestation_type" AS "attestation_type", "created_by"."fullname" AS "created_by", CONCAT("acgti"."ac_customer_version_name", '/', "acgti"."ac_customer_version_rank") AS "ac_version_and_rank" FROM "ac_gti" "acgti" LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "created_by" ON "created_by"."username"="acgti"."created_by"  LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "updated_by" ON "updated_by"."username"="acgti"."updated_by" WHERE "acgti"."ac_production_site" IN ('A350 TJN', 'A350 TLS') ORDER BY "acgti"."rgti_reference" ASC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 20`

Yields different order :

[image]

We couldn't figure why, what is going on here?

Comment: Different rgti_reference orders?

Comment: where is indentation D:

Comment: The optimizer might perhaps find different join orders to be optimal, depending on the number of rows to be returned?

Comment: @jarlh, rgti_references come up in the same order, but the elements order within the same rgti_reference differs

Comment: The general ORDER BY rule is: if you want a specific order, specify it!

Comment: @jarlh, I'm not that proficient in SQL unfortunately. Any way to avoid that if that's the case ?

Comment: See my previous comment!

Comment: @jarlh, makes sense ! I'll try :)

Comment: You'll only get a guaranteed deterministic ordering if you ensure there are sufficient `ORDER BY` expressions to *uniquely* determine the position of each row within the set.

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ORDER BY "acgti"."rgti_reference" ASC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 20`.

Now if there are some result rows where `"acgti"."rgti_reference" IS NULL`, these go first in the result set, and their order is not determined.

Add a second `NOT NULL` column to the `ORDER BY` clause as a tie-breaker to get a deterministic result.